# Where does the loading of keyboard layout happen in android startup?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to understand the process of where keyboard layout is loaded and mapped to the system.

Where is the qwerty.kl config file is been used?

Probably it's in the linux level..

Any references?

Comment: Doing a search now for qwerty.kl using root...

Comment: I have the file, I want to know where it been used..

Answer (score 1):

Here's the qwerty.kl file...

```
key 399   GRAVE
key 2     1
key 3     2
key 4     3
key 5     4
key 6     5
key 7     6
key 8     7
key 9     8
key 10    9
key 11    0
key 158   BACK              WAKE_DROPPED
key 230   SOFT_RIGHT        WAKE
key 60    SOFT_RIGHT        WAKE
key 107   ENDCALL           WAKE_DROPPED
key 62    ENDCALL           WAKE_DROPPED
key 229   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
key 139   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
key 59    MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
key 127   SEARCH            WAKE_DROPPED
key 217   SEARCH            WAKE_DROPPED
key 228   POUND
key 227   STAR
key 231   CALL              WAKE_DROPPED
key 61    CALL              WAKE_DROPPED
key 232   DPAD_CENTER       WAKE_DROPPED
key 108   DPAD_DOWN         WAKE_DROPPED
key 103   DPAD_UP           WAKE_DROPPED
key 102   HOME              WAKE
key 105   DPAD_LEFT         WAKE_DROPPED
key 106   DPAD_RIGHT        WAKE_DROPPED
key 115   VOLUME_UP
key 114   VOLUME_DOWN
key 116   POWER             WAKE
key 212   CAMERA

key 16    Q
key 17    W
key 18    E
key 19    R
key 20    T
key 21    Y
key 22    U
key 23    I
key 24    O
key 25    P
key 26    LEFT_BRACKET
key 27    RIGHT_BRACKET
key 43    BACKSLASH

key 30    A
key 31    S
key 32    D
key 33    F
key 34    G
key 35    H
key 36    J
key 37    K
key 38    L
key 39    SEMICOLON
key 40    APOSTROPHE
key 14    DEL

key 44    Z
key 45    X
key 46    C
key 47    V
key 48    B
key 49    N
key 50    M
key 51    COMMA
key 52    PERIOD
key 53    SLASH
key 28    ENTER

key 56    ALT_LEFT
key 100   ALT_RIGHT
key 42    SHIFT_LEFT
key 54    SHIFT_RIGHT
key 15    TAB
key 57    SPACE
key 150   EXPLORER
key 155   ENVELOPE        

key 12    MINUS
key 13    EQUALS
key 215   AT
```

It's under `system/usr/keylayout` going by your question I assumed that you were asking where it was and how it is mapped, if you provided more info I can help more

Comment: I have this file, I want to know where in the bootstrap or other place in android startup this file is been used. I want to understand which module in the system is loading it? and when/where? (which file?)

Comment: Watched log cat while starting device. Cant see anything there. I dont see any reason while it would be used by anything else other then a character mapping for a keyboard.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the file I realised it contained things like dpad etc. Might need to look into it more.